# Translation filter inside a twig {% raw %} block

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, twig, twig-filter

I have an html template containing some handlebarsjs code that I include in my page to render some product popups. The problem is that those templates are a bit complex and i'd need to translate labels on them too, is there a way to notify an exception to the twig parser? so that, even though the code is inside a `raw` block it is rendered anyway?
Obviously if i use a translation tag it doesn't work `{{ 'translations.project.template.price'|trans }}`

eg:
**`index.html.twig:`**

```
{{ include('WebBundle:Frontend:partials/templates/product-template.html.twig') }}
```

**`product-template.html.twig:`**

```
{% trans_default_domain "home" %}
{% raw %}
  {{#if isLovePromo}}
    <div class="product-infotag promo">
      Promozione <!-- HERE is the text i'd like to translate -->
    </div>
  {{/if}}
{% endraw %}
```

---

At the moment i'm working aroun it by passing the translations to the object rendered by handlebars so i have something like this:

**`index.html.twig:`**

```
data.translations = {
  promo: "{{ 'translations.project.template.promotion'|trans }}"
}
```

template.render(data);
**`product-template.html.twig:`**

```
...
<div class="product-infotag promo">
  {{ promo }} 
</div>
...
```

This method works but it's obviously overkill, i have templates in which i have to pass more than 12 strings and it looks not efficient to me this way.

**Is there a way of addressing this directly in twig?**